# how to remove \r or \n from the data

Tags: r

I found my `Label` file has sth that look like this:

[image]

I would like to remove those. The number of \r and \n are fix number. How should I do that?

I tried following codes but it did not work:

```
Label$Label<- gsub("///r|///n", "",Label$Label)
```

Could someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all control characters:

```
 gsub("[[:cntrl:]]", "", Label$Label)
```

This will remove all \r and \n characters:

```
 gsub("[\r\n]", "", Label$Label)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is using forward slashes instead of backslashes, and it’s using the wrong number. This works:

```
gsub("\\r|\\n", "", Label$Label)
```

Comment: Silly me. Thanks :D